# IntelliJ IDEA - New Template

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to create a set of custom file templates for IntelliJ.

I basically want to go right-click, "New > My File Template" similar to the "New > Java Class" bundled with IntelliJ.

I've added my own custom file template via "Settings > File Templates", but they don't appear in my "New" context menu.

This is a Java project, and my templates extension is java. Am I missing something?

All help greatly appreciated.

[image]

No My Template >>>

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you select Java Class you can then choose the template for your new class. This is a new feature, it used to be available when selecting New.

[image: intellij]

Comment: Thanks for the help, I knew that was there. What I'm after is a completely custom template with my own class body, custom methods, annotations etc.

Comment: I don't think you can add anymore "built in" templates, which is what that list is reserved for. You may be able to do it if you write your own plugin.

Comment: If the extension's `java` for your own custom template, it should appear in the "Kind" drop-down.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can,  sort of.

I don't know know how to do it for Java files. but 
if you set the extension to **txt** you it will show up in the right click menu.
[image: Settings > File Template example]

and here it is in the menu:
[image: right click -> new file -> package-info exists]

the only issue is if you're creating a java class you'll have to rename the file after creation to ${name}.java