# How can I create a template with a default file name in IntelliJIDEA?

Tags: java, templates, intellij-idea, javadoc

How can set a default file name for a template?
I've been going through my code lately adding package-info.java with some info.
I'd like to have IntelliJ IDEA create the file with the correct name and package line so all I have to do is fill in the comment block.

I've figured out a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419606/intellij-idea-new-template) (setting the file extension as **txt**) for the template to be able to create the file. However, I still have to specify the file name as package-info and then rename it from `package-info.txt` to `package-info.java` when I'm done.

Since they will all be named `package-info` I'd like to set this as either part of the template or a default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible until [IDEABKL-5038](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5038) or [IDEA-17910](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-17910) is implemented because Java file templates are handled in a different way.